# Sql Server 2012 Express Remote Connections

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services, sql-server-2012-express

I'm trying to built an application that accesses data from a remote server using a WCF Data Service hosted in an ASP NET App.

And after several days of work I find that I have to configure SQL Server 2012 Express to allow remote connections.

Back in 2005 I did just exactly that, I didn't know that it was still necessary.

My question, is it absolutely necessary for the following platform:

- Visual Studio 2012
- Sql Server Express 2012
- WCF Data Services
- Asp Net app as a host
- Windows 7 Ultimate

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Part of Microsoft's Trustworthy Computing Initiative was to remove as many (default) attack points associated with any of their software/products.  So by default, SQL Server Express only answers to the local machine, windows firewall blocks most incoming ports, and IIS express only answers to localhost (127.0.0.1), etc.